# How can I achieve \verb like behavior with an xparse argspec?

Tags: delimiters, xparse

How can I use a previously scanned token as an argument to `u{}` in an `xparse` argspec?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {some-cool-env} {D<>{\stopscan} u{#1}} {%
  Here is the text up until the stopping token: ``#2'' \newline
  Here's the rest of the environment:                  \par
} {}

\begin{document}
\begin{some-cool-env}
  I am a\stopscan teapot
\end{some-cool-env}

(some inner text)

\begin{some-cool-env}<|>
  A custom built|teapot.
\end{some-cool-env}
\end{document}
```

which would give

```
Here is the text up until the stopping token: "I am a"
Here's the rest of the environment:

teapot

(some inner text)

Here is the text up until the stopping token: "A custom built"
Here's the rest of the environment:

teapot.
```

How might I achieve the syntax I'd like?
(Hopefully without breaking into `xparse`'s internals…)

The naïve approach above produces the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \__xparse_grab_arg:w.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> <to be read again> 
>                    1
> l.9 \DumbVerb
>              <|>test|
> --- HELP ---
> This is probably caused by a \newcommand, \renewcommand,
> \newenvironment, or \renewenvironment command in which a # is used
> incorrectly.  A # character, except as part of the command name \#,
> can be used only to indicate an argument parameter, as in #2, which
> denotes the second argument. This error is also caused by nesting one
> of the above four commands inside another, or by putting a parameter
> like #2 in the last argument of a \newenvironment or \renewenvironment
> command.
> ```

---

I have edited the question body quite a bit since @egreg's answer, but
the question title remains the same.  It should be noted that the
question @egreg answered was for single commands defined with `xparse`.
In such a case his answer would work, but it unfortunately is not
immediately generalizable to defining similar environments.  (Well that's
not true; you can still define an auxiliary environment, but this still
feels like cheating…)

Comment: I've read this several times, but I still can't understand the question.

Comment: I can understand less than before.

Comment: @egreg Hopefully this is clearer? :-/

Comment: You can delimit verbatim arguments only with characters, not with symbolic tokens such as `\delim`.

Comment: @egreg I don't mean to take a verbatim argument, just take the argument with a similar interface as `\verb`.  Note that `{mu{#1}}` allows almost the syntax I need, but obviously `m` is not optional.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably stretching too much `xparse`, but since `mu{#1}` seems to work, you can do it in two stages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\DumbVerb{D<>{|}}{\DumbVerbAux{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\DumbVerbAux{mu{#1}}{Here's #2}
\begin{document}
\DumbVerb test|

\DumbVerb<x>testx

\DumbVerb<\xyz>test\xyz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when defining environments, this doesn't work so well.  It's a solid strategy nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

The [answer from egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151788) is probably the best approach at present, but I'd like to look at this from the point of view of why the desired approach fails. There are essentially two parts to this.

At a technical level, enabling arguments to use information grabbed earlier is (probably) doable but would become very tiresome to do completely generally: imagine a function with nine arguments, here you've got to allow for eight possible previously-grabbed arguments. Using a dedicated auxiliary, as in egreg's answer, avoids this complexity but has to be done on an *ad hoc* basis.

At a conceptual level, `xparse` is intended to create 'LaTeX2e-like' but also 'consistent' document-level interfaces. The problem with the request here is that the interface *isn't* consistent: each time the command is used a different marker has to be scanned for. Ideally such approaches shouldn't pop up in documents, certainly not with any regularity, so the need to support this in `xparse` is far from clear.